# "bash : command not found" error

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, path

I am trying to setup my machine for development and I keep getting the error, `-bash: command not found`.  I am getting while running various commands.  I am brand new to this, trying to get into development, and am not sure how to fix it.  From what I have read it may have something to do with my PATH.  Again, I'm new to this so I really have no clue.

> `new-host:~ Home$ echo $PATH`
>   /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin

Comment: if you run find / -print | xargs grep bash, what's the output?  is that location in your path?

Comment: new-host:~ Home$ find / -print | xargs grep bash
find: /.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /.fseventsd: Permission denied
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied
xargs: grep: Argument list too long

Comment: Are you getting the message with a dash in front as in the question body, or without the dash as in the title? What is the setting of $SHELL?  If it says `/bin/-bash` or `-bash` (with the dash), then reset it without the dash: `SHELL=/bin/bash`. The `-` in front of the name indicates to the shell that it is a login shell and should process `/etc/profile` etc. OTOH, simply setting `SHELL=/bin/-bash` did not routinely cause me problems, even executing plain shell scripts without shebang.

Comment: I am getting the dash in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a bash profile.  So I created one and voila, no more errors.  Thanks again fellas for trying to help a noob!

Comment: Can you please share what you put in your bash profile in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, by default, bash should be located as `/bin/bash`.  So if /bin is not in your path then you need to put it there.  It sounds like you must have been tweaking the base OS X install considerably.  That, or you have installed some packages (macports, fink, brew, etc.???) that have 'adjusted' your path variable, perhaps in undesirable ways.

If you can execute /bin/bash, then you just need to make /bin an entry in your PATH environment variable again.  Places to check:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

Comment: new-host:~ Home$ /etc/profile
-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
new-host:~ Home$ /etc/bashrc
-bash: /etc/bashrc: Permission denied
new-host:~ Home$ ~/.profile
-bash: /Users/Home/.profile: No such file or directory
new-host:~ Home$ ~/.bashrc
-bash: /Users/Home/.bashrc: Permission denied

Comment: Yes, I was also trying to install macports, brew, etc..

Comment: I've used both in the past, without this, but any individual package could have done it.  Another useful thing to do is to create a new user login, and see if it works properly there.  That'll tell you if you have messed it up system wide, or just in your own login account.

Comment: I created a new profile, here is the result:

Comment: new-host:~ dev$ /etc/profile
-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
new-host:~ dev$ /etc/bashrc
-bash: /etc/bashrc: Permission denied
new-host:~ dev$ ~/.profile
-bash: /Users/dev/.profile: No such file or directory
new-host:~ dev$ ~/.bashrc
-bash: /Users/dev/.bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried creating another login account yet to test the system path?

Comment: Yes, that is what I just posted.  Same result.

Comment: Ok, so I wiped my HDD and did a fresh install of 10.8.3.  I created a separate profile for development.  I typed rvm install 1.9.3 and got... -bash: dvm: command not found

Comment: @ibadukefan please see my answer. You didn't need to wipe your system...

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem is bad typing. You get the error `-bash: XXX: command not found` when you type something on the command line that isn't a built-in shell function or external executable program in your path. You got `-bash: dvm: command not found` when you tried to run `rvm` because you typed `dvm` instead.

Your `$PATH` is fine, as `/bin` is right in there in the middle, so there's no problem with `/bin/bash` being found.

In order to see what the contents of `/etc/profile` or `~/.bashrc` are, you can't just type their names, like you were doing in the comments to Randy Howard's question, you have to use a command like `cat /etc/profile` to list its contents.

Comment: I'm limited on my time and I didn't see an answer that helped, so I wiped.  Thanks for the help though.  I was finally able to figure it out and I just created my first ruby on rails app!  Score!  Thanks again.